# Flash library for math equations and graphs, like DragMath and PetitGrapheur

Tags: flash, apache-flex, math, formula, equation

I'm working on e-learning solution and our project requires free or commercial component for math formulas and graphs rendering.

Use cases are:

- built in flash or flex;
- compose math equlation like in in http://www.dragmath.bham.ac.uk/demo.html
- graph rendering like in http://xxi.ac-reims.fr/javamaths/Grapheur/PetitGrapheur.html
- pure client side solution;

So far I found:

1. http://code.google.com/p/mathmlformula/ - really cool, but UI controls are missing (controls like in DragMath).
2. http://validi.fi/latex2flash - but it requires server-side access.
3. http://www.freemathhelp.com/equation-grapher.html - nice graph renderer, mostly satisfy. Need to fix operation priorities (parenthesis).

Please help me with your experience.

Comment: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/the-math-and-actionscript-of-curves-gradients-and-normals/

thic could be in help aswell. :)

Comment: do it like most teachers do, hire yourself a master's degree student to do it for you for free as a thesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fMath for Flex has FREE components for Flex Builder (Web, Desktop-Air and Mobile) to display and edit mathematics equations using MathML, LaTeX or OMML (Microsoft Word) standards.

http://www.fmath.info/flex/download.jsp